# Deleting cities in the ubuntu touch clock app

Tags: ubuntu-touch, core-apps

After accidentally adding a city in the clock app of ubuntu-touch, how can one delete such a city?

Comment: Have you tried holding down on it to see if options come up?

Comment: That was also my reaction. However after your suggestion I tried some more, and the answer is now in my post. Thank you for though!

Comment: Post that as an answer to your question, instead of editing it in. It'll help others for sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. You have to push the entry to the right, then a garbage bin will appear on the left side. This also works in for example Notes.